# I need to Count entries that are duplicated on two unrelated complex queries

Tags: sql, count, subquery, case-when

I have two separate queries that I wrote and am trying to combine, but it's too complex for me.  The first query is a subquery that returns a list of dealer numbers, without any duplicate numbers.  The 2nd query returns a list of dealer numbers, with several duplicate dealer numbers, and the dealer balances.  I need to see how many times the dealer numbers from the 1st query appear in the 2nd query.  Currently, I'm copying and pasting both query results into Excel, then using a Countif function to see how many times the dealers from the first query appear in the second query.

Is there a way to do the entire process in SQL?

Query 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT(X.PARENTS) AS "UNIQUE PARENTS" FROM ( SELECT

CASE WHEN  PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END AS "PARENTS",

CASE WHEN ((SUM(decode(CUSTMR_COLLAT_TYPE_DESCR,'New Car',1,0)) ) ) <> 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "FRANCHISE"

FROM MONTH_END_TABLE

WHERE TRUST_ID IS NOT NULL AND EXTRCT_FILE_DT = '30-JUN-2017'

GROUP BY CASE WHEN  PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END, CUSTMR_NBR
) X

WHERE X.FRANCHISE = 'N'
```

Query 2

```
SELECT CASE WHEN  PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END AS "DUPLICATE PARENTS",

SUM(CURR_PRINCPL_AMT)

FROM MONTH_END_TABLE

WHERE TRUST_ID IS NOT NULL

AND EXTRCT_FILE_DT = '30-JUN-2017'

AND (CASE WHEN  PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END <>CUSTMR_NBR)

GROUP BY CASE WHEN  PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END, CUSTMR_NBR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR) From
(
SELECT DISTINCT(X.PARENTS) AS "UNIQUE PARENTS" FROM ( SELECT

CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR 
END AS "PARENTS",

CASE WHEN ((SUM(decode(CUSTMR_COLLAT_TYPE_DESCR,'New Car',1,0)) ) ) <> 0 
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "FRANCHISE"

FROM MONTH_END_TABLE

WHERE TRUST_ID IS NOT NULL AND EXTRCT_FILE_DT = '30-JUN-2017'

GROUP BY CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END, CUSTMR_NBR ) X

WHERE X.FRANCHISE = 'N')
Where PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR
IN
(SELECT CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END AS "DUPLICATE PARENTS",

SUM(CURR_PRINCPL_AMT)

FROM MONTH_END_TABLE

WHERE TRUST_ID IS NOT NULL

AND EXTRCT_FILE_DT = '30-JUN-2017'

AND (CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END <>CUSTMR_NBR)

GROUP BY CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END, CUSTMR_NBR)
```

Comment: I think that was very close, thanks for the help!  

Unfortunately the part of the code "CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END" can't be shortened to "PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR".

I was hoping a subquery might fix it, but no luck.

Comment: You can use alias for that, like :    CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END AS "PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR"

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, thanks to your help Suresh!  Here's the final query:

```
Select Count(DUPPARENTS) From

(SELECT CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END AS "DUPPARENTS"

FROM MONTH_END_TABLE

WHERE TRUST_ID IS NOT NULL

AND EXTRCT_FILE_DT = '30-JUN-2017'

AND (CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END <>CUSTMR_NBR)

GROUP BY CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END, CUSTMR_NBR)

Where (DUPPARENTS) IN

(SELECT DISTINCT(X.UNIPARENTS) FROM ( SELECT

CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR 
END AS "UNIPARENTS",

CASE WHEN ((SUM(decode(CUSTMR_COLLAT_TYPE_DESCR,'New Car',1,0)) ) ) <> 0 
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS "FRANCHISE"

FROM MONTH_END_TABLE

WHERE TRUST_ID IS NOT NULL AND EXTRCT_FILE_DT = '30-JUN-2017'

GROUP BY CASE WHEN PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR IS NULL THEN CUSTMR_NBR ELSE 
PARENT_CUSTMR_NBR END, CUSTMR_NBR ) X

WHERE X.FRANCHISE = 'N')
```